# how to improve Android client and PHP server security?

Tags: php, android, security, server

I want use POST to Transfer data between PHP server and Android client, how to improve security? For example, how can you ensure that believable and successful access to the server API can only be my Android client?

because of app have Login mechanism, so I think I should add the account verification code in every post(It consists of user password and so on, may be encrypted by MD5), Then every POST have clear sources, if the source is invalid(don't have verification code or it's wrong), Server denial of service. Is this feasible?

Comment: use https connection , send post data with encoding and also use auth token in header

Comment: u can implement OAuth

Comment: You can never be 100% certain that the request comes from the actual app. If a request comes from a client that users have access to, the user can, theoretically, always check how the app is making the request and fake it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "How to..."? "For example..."? This is too broad of a question for SO. Please do research using web search engines. Also please read this before posting any more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @MaciejJureczko I released my ask again, and explain my specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web service first of all. This would allow you to filter requests coming from the Android client by their method, for example only handing `POST` for certain end points.

If you knew that only an Android client would be accessing your server you could also enforce that a "client" or "auth" token (simply a JSON property) must be sent with every request and you would then only supply this token to the Android client implementation and refuse any attempt to access your server which didn't include the token.

It's also important not to access superglobals such as `$_POST` in PHP directly, instead use [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

This is just a suggestion and there is much more you can do.

Comment: Setting up a RESTful web service isn't more secure than any other type of web service. Regarding Client- and Auth-tokens, someone can easily decompile the app and get them. Then they can make the request from anywhere.

Comment: I think it definitely helps to structure a client - server system and makes it far easier to extend and add security into. I believe this does help with the OP's question of how to improve the security.

Comment: Structuring an app properly and to follow standards will of course always help out in development. My point was that a RESTful web service on it's own isn't more secure than any other standard. You will always need to actually implement the security, regardless. I think the question in itself is too broad, since there are so many things to think about. It all depends on what the app actually does as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson agreed